# How to auth user for login in laravel using auth()

Tags: laravel

i have started learning laravel and i am trying to create login.
i have tried this

**route**

```
Route::post('userLogin', [\App\Http\Controllers\LoginController::class,'userLogin'])->name('userLogin');
```

**blade.php**

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('userLogin') }}">
    @csrf
.........
</form>
```

**controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Login;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;


class LoginController extends Controller
{

    public function userLogin(Request $request){
        $email = $request['email'];
        $pass = $request['pass'];

        if (auth()->attempt(['u_email' => $email, 'u_pass' => $pass])){
            print 'ok';
        }
        else{
            print 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem**

it is showing none, i have tried to print the values before `auth()` it print correct values.

Any solution

Comment: Would the documentation on [Manually Authenticating Users](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticating-users) help?

Answer (score 0):

Use email and password instead of u_email and u_pass

Answer (score 0):

You **must** pass the password as the field named 'password' in the credentials passed to `Auth::attempt`. This does not directly relate to the field in the table but the system needs to know what field in the credentials is the password so it can not include it in the query and then do a hash check against it if it finds a record. All the credentials passed to `attempt` except the 'password' field are `where` conditions on the query.

If you need to adjust what the password field is for that model you must adjust it on the model using the `getAuthPassword` method.